# Get the Max value of a row and get its' column name along with an additional column in the output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have the following data frame:

[image]

I want to get the highest value from each row in the data frame and get it's corresponding column name along with the ItemName column as well like this:

[image]

I was able to get the Max Values using this code:

```
result = new_df.max(axis=1)
result.index = new_df.idxmax(axis=1)
print(result)
```

Ouput:

[image]

How do I include the ItemName Column as well in the output to get the following format?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) :

```
result = (new_df.set_index('ItemName')
                .agg(['max','idxmax'], axis=1)
                .set_axis(['MaxValue','ColumnName'], axis=1)
                .reset_index())

print (result)
  ItemName MaxValue ColumnName
0      AAA      0.9          A
1      BBB      0.7          C
2      CCC      0.8          C
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = new_df.set_index('ItemName')

result = (pd.concat([df.max(axis=1), df.idxmax(axis=1)], 
                    axis=1, 
                    keys=('MaxValue','ColumnName'))
                 .reset_index())
print (result)
  ItemName  MaxValue ColumnName
0      AAA       0.9          A
1      BBB       0.7          C
2      CCC       0.8          C
```

Or use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with remove  column by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = new_df.drop('ItemName', axis=1)

result = new_df[['ItemName']].assign(MaxValue = df.max(axis=1),
                                     ColumnName= df.idxmax(axis=1))

print (result)
  ItemName  MaxValue ColumnName
0      AAA       0.9          A
1      BBB       0.7          C
2      CCC       0.8          C
```